# Show the list of users who +1 or liked a Google Reader feed item

Tags: google-reader, google-plus, google-plus-1

How, or where, do you find the list of Google+ users who have read things in Google Reader and hit that +1 like button?

At the tail end of an item in Google Reader there is this social button section that allows you to +1 or share:

[image: what does it all mean?]

Hover over the button and you'll see a prompt to "Publicly +1 this".

When you do it adds it to your +1 tab in your Google Plus profile.

But how do you see who else hit that button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Google+ Buttons Policy](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html) states:

> Publishers may not attempt to discover the identity of a Google+ Button user unless the user consents to share his or her identity with the Publisher via a Google-approved authorization procedure.

I don't think you can see a list of people that clicked the +1 Button. "Publicly +1 this" means that anyone who can see your Google profile can see that you +1'd that item, not that there is a list somewhere.

Comment: That's deflating. But then if it's public and there's an approved procedure, that could show a list of all those public +1s in a single place

Comment: Is there any way to know how many of the feed subscribers read a specific item in google reader? (regardless of whether they +1ed it)